# Font size and actual text size proportion

Tags: fonts, size

I know that the actual size occupied by a rendered text is font-dependent.

For a predetermined font, however, and knowing the `font_size/actual_width` proportion for a given font size and a particular text, is it possible to determine the width for another value of size?

I guess what I'm really asking is: is the relation between a font size in pixels and the actual rendered size of a text linear?